# Without a single word

Tags: geometry, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, symbols

[image: Strange dots]

Answer is a well-known object, which at the same time is a location name. I'll post additional hints if needed.

**Hint 1:**

> The cube is not really a cube. Along with three polygons it designates much more complex yet well-known 3D shape.

**Edit:** More visual hints.

Comment: The top left symbol looks like the Chinese character for "king". If we interpret the middle shapes as chemicals, we get cyclopentadienyl, benzene, and naphthalene respectively. Not sure where this could be going though...

Comment: @Deusovi No special symbol knowledge is needed to solve this. The idea about chemicals is interestring, but I haven't thought about them when making this puzzle (surprisingly enough, you can solve it if you interpret them as chemicals too).

Comment: I've updated the puzzle. Unfortunately for you guys the edit affects only a later part of it, beginning remains as hard as it was before. :P

Comment: I think the answer is one of the shapes from that ring of shapes, and that the other stuff is referring to some kind of derived properties of the shapes or the way the striped one is turned into 2D  and how that applies to the shapes and the shapes are ordered by something.

Comment: @godofllamas Answer is a thing designated by the large question mark on the left. Is it one of the shapes? Maybe.

Comment: Maybe the answer it's a football stadium but there many things do not make sense.

Comment: @nikamed This is not a football stadium, but looks like you've solved at least a part of the puzzle correctly. Maybe you can post this solved part for others to see?

Comment: Given the hint and the shapes, I believe the "cube" is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron (ie a soccer ball).

Comment: I came up with testicle:)

Comment: @RobertFraser Well, congrats, you've guessed right! But can you solve remaining part of the puzzle?

Comment: The stripy cube-looking thing could be a Moebius strip; no clue as to the full answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Saturn

because

> It is the 6th planet of solar system and has 62 moons

Explanation:

> The first part of the puzzle is this: 
>  [image: ---] 
>  Black stripes on the cube signify black polygons: 
>  [image: ---] 
>  At this point the cube starts to resemble an unfinished soccer ball. It's time to attach more polygons: 
>  [image: ---] 
>  And even more polygons! 
>  [image: ---] 
>  Looks good. Now, let's look at this part: 
>  [image: ---] 
>  This scheme makes me think that those symbols under the polygons are numbers. Then, let's count the polygons! 
>  [image: ---] 
>  In total: 6 double hexagons, 8 normal hexagons and 12 pentagons. 
>  Thus, there are 8 objects (+1 tiny) and we're interested in the 12-6 = 6th one.
> But what objects are we counting? 
>  Let's look at this: 
>  [image: ---] 
>  The question mark with some objects in the middle just means "What shape?". Our cube is a soccer ball, which is a "hollow truncated icosahedron". But from the practical point of view it's just a sphere.
> So, we're counting spheres. We have some unknown object and 8 spheres and 1 tiny sphere. This highly resemples our solar system: black circle = Sun, 8 spheres = planets, tiny sphere = Pluto, arcs below = orbits. 
>  Thus, sixth sphere = Saturn? Look at following part: 
>  [image: ---] 
>  There are 62 dots and Saturn has 62 moons. Black ring may designate Saturn's rings. 
>  And the huge question mark below that drawing unambiguously shows that the thing depicts an object we're looking for.
>  The answer is Saturn. Puzzle solved!

**Edit:** Added better explanation.

Comment: 11 planets in the solar system?

Comment: If you try hard:)

Comment: Congratulations, you've got it! But why 11 planets total? You've said that Z = 8 yourself.

Comment: This is very clever.

Comment: @I was counting the dots considering astrology. Confused some.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Even with the answer I don't seem to understand most of the image, yet. Would you as OP care to add some explainations? I feel that this puzzle is well made but might deserve a better "answer" for people reading it in future. There is so much going on in the image...

Comment: @BmyGuest You're right, it needs a better answer. Here is is.

Comment: No need to get up your temper, nikamed. I didn't think your answer bad or your work for that matter. I was rather asking you or the OP to improve on it, as it wasn't quite clear for me from the text written. The quotation marks were not needed, I agree, but they were also not meant negatively. Sorry, if I insulted you in any way, wasn't meant that way.